# Dimension of scalar solutions to these self-dual/anti-self-dual equations

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a 4-dimensional Riemannian manifold. Let $\kappa$ be a 1-form.

I look for solution function $\phi$, such that there exists functions $\alpha$ and $\beta$
\begin{equation}
    {\left( {d\phi  \wedge \kappa } \right)^ + } = \alpha d{\kappa ^ + },\;\;\;\;{\left( {d\phi  \wedge \kappa } \right)^ - } = \beta {\left( {d\kappa } \right)^ - }
\end{equation}

Obviously, constant function $\phi$ is one solution, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both zero. But I wonder if there are more solutions in general, and how to construct them?

---

**Example**

On $S^4$, picking $\kappa = {\sin ^2}\rho \left( {{{\cos }^2}\theta d{\varphi _1} + {{\sin }^2}\theta d{\varphi _2}} \right)$, with spherical coordinate
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
  {x_0} = \cos \rho  \hfill \\
  {x_1} = \sin \rho \cos \theta \cos {\varphi _1} \hfill \\
  {x_2} = \sin \rho \cos \theta \sin {\varphi _1} \hfill \\
  {x_3} = \sin \rho \sin \theta \cos {\varphi _2} \hfill \\
  {x_4} = \sin \rho \sin \theta \sin {\varphi _2} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
\end{equation}

one can find a non-trivial solution $\phi \sim \cos \rho$.